# Excel Web Query Issues

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

I'm having troubles adding parameters to a Web Query that reads currency rates from an Excel cell. I need it to read it through the cell because the data needs to be updated constantly and the date formatting is different than the standard format.

**Parameter:** date format that updates daily (YEARMONTHDAY) in Cell ("A1") - As ["datums"]

**URL:** http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml?date=**["datums"]**

**Error - in URL:**
[image]

**Error - in Excel:**
[image]

**Excel - Parameter:**
[image]

Comment: Up marking this because I've never used this functionality in excel so would like to know the answer. I did try this with the XML you provided and it worked for me but with the following error **`DTD is prohibited`** (line 2, column 11)

Comment: **Update**: I tried specifying the cell and got the same error as you.. I'll dig a bit more